# Binding ints, longs and blobs (byte[]) to android sql

Tags: android, sqlite

The `query()`, `exec()` and `rawQuery()` methods in the `SQLiteDatabase` allow binding only `String`s to parameters. How do I bind parameters that are not Strings.  Specifically, I would like to execute a statement whose `where` clause contains a parameter that is a (small) blob. How do I bind such values

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your type to `String` before passing it to any of the methods.

To convert an int, use the static method [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29). Similarly, to convert a long, use the static method [`Long.toString(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString%28long%29).

In case of `byte[]` you can use the [`String(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29) or [`String(byte[], Charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) constructor. You will need to ensure that you use appropriate and consistent encoding.

Comment: Thanks. Just a clarification: When you suggest " ensure that you use appropriate and consistent encoding", are you suggesting that I choose a Charset and hard-code it so that the statement is correctly bound on all devices where the default Charset may be different? In this case, can I choose UTF-8 everywhere?

Comment: Yes, by consistent I meant that you may need to ensure that the same encoding is used every time you perform this transformation. UTF-8 isn't a good choice since not all byte sequences are valid UTF-8 encodings.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you may also want to check out [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: The column in question is a 16-byte random UUID where the 8th bit in every byte is not guaranteed to be '0'. Would 'base64' be appropriate in this case?

Comment: Yes, that would work, base64 can encode arbitrary byte sequences, but it'd increase your storage by ca 33%.

Comment: Sorry, I probably mis-represented my problem: I have a blob column in which I want to insert a 16-byte byte[]. I do not want to store an encoded version of my binary string precisely to avoid the storage overhead. What is the Android/Java  equivalent of the C-API `sqlite3_bind_blob`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8510/discussion-between-ya-perelman-and-adam-zalcman)

Comment: Right, in that case you can simply perform the conversion as above.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLiteStatement.compileStatement()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) is what you're looking for